# Compile Boost on WIndows XP

Tags: gcc, boost, mingw

I am trying to compile the Boost library for Windows (as a prerequisite for building the Bitcoin client), using the MinGW compiler toolchain to do so (rather than Visual Studio) and running into errors.

Following various guides online, I have a working `bjam` application, and the `boost_1_55_0` source files. I have tried in the windows shell doing:

- `path/to/bjam.exe toolset=gcc --build-type=complete stage` (the instructions that Bitcoin provides), but get `mingw.jam: No such file or directory` errors
- `bootstrap mingw` from a standard DOS shell runs successfully, but the `.\b2` after emits a bunch of `'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` errors, implying it's not really set up to use gcc/mingw, since it's calling for the Microsoft compiler.
- `bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=mingw` from the MSYS prompt (as suggested [here](http://vijay.axham.com/blog/478/building-boost-binaries-on-mingw), which creates a log file that doesn't have as many errors, but running `./b2` after leads to a `mingw.jam no such file` error, and `mingw.init unknown` error.
- Downloading the compiled binaries from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0/ (boost_1_55_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe). After extracting and referring to the `lib` and header files, compiling the final executable throws a whole bunch of `undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'` for various boost features, implying to me the library files aren't actually containing the proper definitions? Is that because they're Visual Studio libraries?
- Downloading the archives from http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html (boost_1_55_0.7z), which the documentation implies comes with a pre-compiled `lib` dir, but does not in fact.

So, I'm banging my head on several walls at once. Can anyone help me get past any of these roadblocks?

Comment: "which the documentation implies comes with a pre-compiled lib dir" -- how does it imply that? I'm afraid it doesn't. Bootsraping from MSys shell with `--with-toolset=mingw` parameter` and then building Boost libraries is the right way to go. Instead of running `./b2` try: `./b2 toolset=gcc` (in MSys shell).

Comment: @IgorR. The documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html claims in the first paragraph, you just need to "unpack it to install a complete Boost distribution" and the directory tree right below it includes a `lib` folder, both of which originally implied to me that the download would already include that.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following steps to successfully build boost version 1.54 in a MinGW/MSYS environment:

1. Build `bjam.exe` and `b2.exe`:
   `boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2\engine>build.bat mingw`
2. Copy build tools to the root-directory:
   `cp boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2\engine\bin.ntx86\*.exe boost_1_54_0`
3. Run `bjam.exe`:
   `bjam --toolset=gcc --build -type=complete install > boost_build.log`

I used this process with slight variations for various boost versions, so its a good guess it will work for 1.55 too